# Google Sheets, Multiple IF, AND Statements with point ranges

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, nested

So I am using a google spreadsheet to track students points on a math test. I give them a grade based on their points and there end up being a lot of alternatives. We have levelled points so the information below shows first the grade they would get then the total points they got and then the C or higher level points they have.

```
E   5 pts

D   7 pts 2 c+

C   9 pts 3 c+

B   11pts 5 c+ 

A   13 pts 6 c+
```

Currently, I have a Google sheet that tallies up there points when I input and I have a column for total points and C or higher points.

I was attempting to do it with multiple IF and AND statements but it isn't working correctly (I end up with the wrong Grade coming out)

Here is the code I tried:

```
=If(W3<5,"F",IF(AND(W3>=5,X3<2),"E",If(AND(W3>=7,1<X3<3),"D",If(AND(7<W3<9,X3>=2),"D",IF(AND(W3>=9,2<X3<5),"C",IF(AND(8<W3<11,X3>=3),"C",IF(AND(W3>=11,4<X3<6),"B",IF(AND(10<W3<13,X3>=5),"B","A"))))))))
```

I'm hoping there is an easier way to do this or someone spots my mistake. It isn't the end of the world if it isn't possible because I can just look at the results but it is more fun to be able to figure out how to have it down automatically.

Answer (score 0):

`ARRAYFORMULA` variant of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55243240) which will auto-populate grades for all rows. can be pasted in any column on the second row

```
={"GRADE"; 
 ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(W3:W),
              IF(W3:W<5,  "F",
              IF(W3:W<7,  "E",
              IF(X3:X<2,  "E",
              IF(W3:W<9,  "D",
              IF(X3:X<3,  "D",
              IF(W3:W<11, "C",
              IF(X3:X<5,  "C",
              IF(W3:W<12, "B",
              IF(X3:X<6,  "B", "A"))))))))), ))}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google sheets doesn't like logical expressions with more than one operator (e.g., `1<X3<2`), so those will need to be broken up into two expressions with the `AND()` operator (e.g., `AND(1<X3, X3<2)`).

There seem to be some holes in the possible value combinations though, which become obvious if you graph them out:

[image]

A simpler way to write the logic would be to take a kind of "weaving" pattern to each successive conditional, as illustrated below. This approach lets us avoid having to describe ranges or use `AND()` operators, and ensures there are no combinations that are undefined.

[image]

This approach can be described in pseudocode as:

```
1:  if      (W3 < 5)  F
2:  else if (W3 < 7)  E
3:  else if (X3 < 2)  E
4:  else if (W3 < 9)  D
5:  else if (X3 < 3)  D
6:  else if (W3 < 11) C
7:  else if (X3 < 5)  C
8:  else if (W3 < 12) B
9:  else if (X3 < 6)  B
10: else              A
```

The Google Sheets formula for this would be:

```
=IF(W3<5,"F",IF(W3<7,"E",IF(X3<2,"E",IF(W3<9,"D",IF(X3<3,"D",IF(W3<11,"C",IF(X3<5,"C",IF(W3<12,"B",IF(X3<6,"B","A")))))))))
```

Answer (score -1):

One method is to use the `AND` operator repeatedly to limit the value range. If the answer can be further simplified, please kindly share in this post.

The following code demonstrates how to use `AND` operators repeatedly to limit the value range:

```
=If(W3<5,"F",IF(AND(W3>=5,X3<2),"E",If(AND(W3>=7,1<X3<3),"D",If(AND(AND(6<W3,W3<9),X3>=2),"D",IF(AND(W3>=9,AND(2<X3,X3<5)),"C",IF(AND(AND(8<W3,W3<11),X3>=3),"C",IF(AND(W3>=11,AND(4<X3,X3<6)),"B",IF(AND(AND(10<W3,W3<13),X3>=5),"B",IF(AND(W3>=13,X3>=6),"A","undefined")))))))))
```